# Not getting response from jsp page

Tags: php, jquery, jsp

I am submitting a page from php to jsp using jquery ajaxSubmit. In jsp page every thing is doing well but after completing the work done i did not get any response data. my code in php page is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
var options = {
    url: "http://localhost:8084/aProject/clientRequest/receiveClientRequest.jsp",
    type: "post",
    data: { id: "001", name: "Mujahid Khan"},
    resetForm: false,
    success: function(data){
        alert($.trim(data));                    
    }                   
};

$("#frmEmpInfo").submit(function(){
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
});    
</script>
<form id="frmEmpInfo" name="frmEmpInfo">
   <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Send" style=" width: 80px; height: 30px;" />  
</form>
```

and the JSP page code is

```
<%
String id = request.getParameter("id").trim();
String name = request.getParameter("name").trim();

%>
<div>ID: <%=id%> , Name: <%=name%> </div>
```

I want to get a alert " ID: 001, Name: Mujahid Khan "

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the JSP page code

```
<div>ID: <%=id%> , Name: <%=name%> </div>
```

this wont work. And it may create a runtime error.
Try this. Replace that part of code with below.

```
<div>ID: <%=out.print(id)%> , Name: <%=out.print(name)%> </div>
```

Comment: There is no run time error. If i send the same request from jsp page. It works fine. I replaced the code but not getting response till now.